# Wordpress sidebar not showing with administrator acess

Tags: php, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I'm having a problem on a website here, where my user, even with administrator privileges, doesn't see all the options in the menu. In fact, no user appears. I've already checked the WP-CONFIG and INDEX.php files and I don't know what else to do. Does anyone know a solution or have faced this error?
NOTE: I've already tried updating the theme, deactivating, deactivating plugins.

[Print here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFpOh.png)

I changed the theme, deactivated the plugin and theme, and nothing helped. I believe it is a problem with the database or some configuration.

Comment: _"In fact, no user appears"_ - are you talking about the default admin item entry to view/edit user accounts here? According to your screenshot, you appear to be in a specific menu sub-section "Qode options" there, and I don't think the default user menu point should be _in_ there ...?